# Angular/Jade t() method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am currently working on taking apart a web application so that I can learn to build one myself.  Right now, I'm examining the front end, but there's several lines of code in my templates that use the method t(variable).  I looked all throughout the project, but I cannot seem to find out what it does.  Here's the rest of the context:

```
    body(ng-app='FruitApp', ng-controller='MainController')
    +custom_header('fruit manager', 'exit')
    block content

    +custom_footer(t('layout.footer.about'))
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: maybe some more context would be helpful: `label.mdl-textfield__label !{t('index.card.name')}`

Comment: the template is in jade as well